# Como obter o retorno (value) de uma Promise em JavaScript / TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript, ionic2, angular

Estou iniciando com Ionic 2, que utiliza o Angular 2, e estou tentando entender como funcionam promises, pois algumas libs que estou utilizando trabalham possuem funções que retornam promises e gostaria de obter o valor retornado, porém o retorno é sempre **undefined**:

Ex.:

'classe' Storage:

```
public get(key: string) {
    localforage.getItem(key).then(function (value) {

      console.log(value); // exibe o value normalmente, ex.: {nome: 'Joao', idade: '20'}
      return value;

    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

'classe' Page1:

```
recuperarItem() {
    var object = this.storage.get('pessoa1');

    console.log(object); // undefined
}
```

Como faço para obter o **retorno** desta forma? Grato pela atenção.

Comment: Não seria nessa parte `localforage`? O correto é localStorage

Comment: Estou utilizando a biblioteca localforage neste exemplo - https://mozilla.github.io/localForage/ - mas a dúvida se aplicaria a qualquer Promise

Answer (score 3):

Isso acontece pois a sua função `get` não retorna nada, repare que o seu return está dentro de uma função anonima e não na função `get`

Em geral as Promises são usadas em programação assíncrona, é basicamente uma alternativa aos callbacks, onde na verdade você ainda está usando callbacks, uma forma de corrigir o seu problema seria retornando o `Promise` na função `get`

```
public get(key: string) {
    return localforage.getItem(key).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

E então na função `recuperarItem` você espera o promise ser resolvido

```
recuperarItem() {
    this.storage.get().then(function (value) {
        console.log(value);         
    })
}
```

Agora dependendo se o target do TypeScript for es6/es2015 você tem a opção de usar o async/await, seu código ficaria assim

```
public get(key: string) {
    return localforage.getItem(key).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

E então na função `recuperarItem` nós deixamos o TypeScript fazer sua mágica com o async await

```
async recuperarItem() {
    var object = await this.storage.get();
    console.log(value);         
}
```

Porém lembrando que es6/es2015 ainda não é suportado pela maioria dos navegadores e não sei dizer no caso do Ionic 2 como está o suporte ou se precisa usar algum transpiler como o [Babel](http://babeljs.io)

Comment: O problema era justamente o que você falou. Naquela época não sabia trabalhar com promises ainda, e você esclareceu bem, obrigado! Desculpe a demora pelo retorno.

Answer (score 1):

Tente desta forma:

```
...
localforage.getItem(key).then((value) => {
...
```